# Why is poetry not updating git+ssh dependency from private repo versioned using git tag?

Tags: python, git, ssh, python-poetry

I have two python projects, lib and app, managed through poetry. Lib is on github in a private repo and the version in its pyproject.toml is 0.2.0. This is tagged in github with git tag v0.2.0.

Access to the gh private repo is enabled by adding my ssh public key to my gh account [using these instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account). Lib is then made a dependency of app using

```
poetry add git+ssh://git@github.com:org/lib.git#v0.2.0
```

in the app folder and this creates the dependency in pyproject.toml of app with the line

```
lib = {git = "git@github.com:org/lib.git", rev = "v0.2.0"}
```

So far, so good.

Now I make a change to lib and the version increases to 0.2.1 in pyproject.toml. The code is pushed to gh and tagged with git tag v0.2.1. I try to update the dependecy in app using

```
poetry update lib
```

in the app folder but it doesn't work. Neither does `poetry lock`.

As a worksaround, if I issue the command

```
poetry add git+ssh://git@github.com:org/lib.git#v0.2.1
```

then it updates without issue, however I would like poetry to check for updates with just

```
poetry update
```

or

```
poetry update lib
```

I have seen that this is possible for public repos (using https) and also (I think, but could be mistaken) where the git+ssh url is pinned to a branch, say `#latest`. However I cannot get it to work with a tagged version.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this with this line in my `pyproject.toml`:

```
lib = { git = "ssh://git@github.com/yourOrg/name-of-your-repo.git", tag = "your-tag-here" }
```